# Issue with Hibernate session.createQuery(from TableProcess).list(); does not work

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I've been working with Netbeans and MySQL lately to create a Spring+Hibernate application, but I've been facing some issues in my block of code:

```
public List listSystemProcess() {
        List procesosSistema = null;
        String hbQuery = "from TableProcess";

        try {
            Session hbSesion = HibernatePersistenceHandler.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Transaction tx = hbSesion.beginTransaction();
            Query query = hbSesion.createQuery(hbQuery);
            procesosSistema = query.list();
            tx.commit();
            hbSesion.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return procesosSistema;
    }
```

This does not works at all, I get something related to SQL syntax exception, telling me there's a syntax error near "select id2_1,uj8_,5sd_11 from tb_2_1..."

If I create a SQLQuery instead of an HQL one, it works perfectly, but I do not find useful to do this since I should be doing this for each single process, and that's tedious and it's almost the same than use JDBC.

This works:

```
String hbQuery = "select p.id,p.nombre,p.descripcion,p.frecuencia_uso,t.nombre "
        + "from tb_proceso_sistema p inner join tb_tipo_proceso t "
        + "on p.tb_tipo_proceso_id = t.id";
    Query query = hbSesion.createSQLQuery(hbQuery);
```

But when I do this, as well, my jsp changes a bit:

```
<c:forEach items="${procesosSistema}" var="proceso">
                <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';"
            onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
                    <td><c:out value="${proceso[0]}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${proceso[1]}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${proceso[2]}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${proceso[3]}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${proceso[4]}"/></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

instead of:

```
<c:forEach items="${procesosSistema}" var="proceso">
                <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';"
            onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
                    <td><c:out value="${proceso.id}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${proceso.nombre}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${proceso.descripcion}"/></td>
                     ...
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

When I set in properties "show_sql", it shows a strange query as shown above, something like:

```
"select id2_1,uj8_,5sd_11 from SGDP-mysql123.tb_2_1.... tb0"
```

If somebody could help me please, I would be really grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have a doubt here, you mentioned

String hbQuery = "from TableProcess";

Is your "TableProcess" class has a mapping in the hbm.xml file with the table ?

And if you are using inner join as in the second query, then there cannot be such mapping, you have to use it like this only.

Answer (score 1):

if "TableProcess" class has mapping in hbm.xml and exist table in database, try this code:

```
public List listSystemProcess() {
    List<TableProcess> procesosSistema = null;
    String hbQuery = "SELECT p FROM TableProcess p";

    Session hbSesion = null;
    try {
        Session hbSesion =HibernatePersistenceHandler.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Query query = hbSesion.createQuery(hbQuery);
        procesosSistema = query.list();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    } finaly{
        hbSesion.close();
    }

    return procesosSistema;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi to everybody who answer to this question, but it was not a problem with the code but with the name of the tables and columns, since most of them contains the character "*", when Hibernate generates a query, it uses "*" as a character for its "encoding" or its "querying process". I mean, one of the columns was called process_id and frequence_number, but since that character is not admitted, I needed to replace it by processId and frequenceNumber (I don't know why, maybe because Hibernate considers it as a part of its encoding or something like that). What I needed to do, as I mentioned, is to fix the name of tables and columns to avoid using "_", after solving this, I needed to re-generate all my database mappings stuff and change the names for the new ones. Then it worked perfetly, hope this issue could help somebody with the same problem.

Thanks everybody for the answers, for sure I tried and maybe they would be useful in a similar scenario.